# A derivative with respect to Euclidean distance?

Tags: derivatives, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

I have a function $y (x,z)$ from $\mathbb{R}_+^4$ to $\mathbb{R}$,  where $x,z \in \mathbb{R}_+^2$.

I want to turn the following statement into math:
"the function $y$ is increasing as the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $z$ is increasing"

Can I write $\frac{ d y(x,z) }{\mathbb d c(x,z)}>0$, where $c(x,z)$ is the Euclidean distance between $x$ and $z$?

Comment: I think y must be a function of (x1-z1)^2+(x2-z2)^2 , & remain constant when this is constant.

Comment: I am taking x=(x1,x2) & z=(z1,z2)

Comment: Now, when we eliminate x1,x2,z1,z2 to make y a function of only D^2=(x1-z1)^2+(x2-z2)^2 , then we can make dy/dD Positive.

Comment: So $y$ is actually from $\mathbb{R}_{+}^2 \times \mathbb{R}_{+}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}$, I think.

Comment: I have made that correction, Nice Catch @aschepler